# Determine whether a field has changed during hook_node_submit

Tags: hooks, nodes

Basically I need a way of checking whether a node field changed during some event hook...I am using hook_node_submit() but this doesn't seem to work:

```
$form['field_status']['und']['#value'] !== $node->field_status['und'][0]['value']
```

Produces equality all the time...any suggestions on which hook and how I would check equality when I know a value has changed it should fire off an email...

Alex

Comment: If you use `hook_node_update()` you should have access to `$node->original` (copy of the original object). Not sure if it's available in `hook_node_submit()`

Answer (score 1):

As said from @Clive, the only way is to compare the value in `$node` with the value contained in `$node->original`.

As far as I can see, that value is only available in [`hook_node_update()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7.x), [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x) and every hook invoked from [`node_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7.x) which receive the saved node as argument (but only when a node is updated), since [`entity_load_unchanged()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load_unchanged/7) is called from [`node_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7) (which also unset `$node->original` before exiting). If you need it in [`hook_node_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7.x) you could simply add the following code in your implementation.

```php
if (!empty($node->nid) && !isset($node->original)) {
  $node->original = entity_load_unchanged('node', $node->nid);
}
```

Since you are checking for field properties, the other, more general, hook would be [`hook_field_attach_submit(hook_field_attach_submit($entity_type, $entity, $form, &$form_state))`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_submit/7). With this hook, `$entity` would contain the field value before the node has been edited, and `$form_state` contains the submitted values.